# How do you rearrange buttons where you want them in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey guys I am having trouble with placing my buttons in my XML layout. I already have a background and was just trying to put 3 buttons near the middle and thats where I'm having trouble. I know about center gravity and all that but could you help me? Also, If I made my own buttons can I just import them using the image button thing, or is that not right? Thanks for the help!

PS: Also, there is a big white box around my button. How do I get that to go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this answer to your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935660/how-do-you-rearrange-buttons-in-eclipse/6935693#6935693), so I'll also post it here. :)

You can rearrange elements of your layout by editing the XML directly or by dragging and dropping in the outline view or the graphical layout view (I find the latter harder to do reliably).

To use your custom views, click on the "Custom & Library Views" button in the graphical layout palette, or just type in the fully qualified class name as the view tag in the XML.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess thats why duplicate questions are bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Image button you can set your custom Image to src property or background property. If youi chose src you should add android:background="@null".

But I would recommend to use background property while if you use 9-patch png (who knows maybe tomorow you will use 9-patch) they would not stretch if you set it in src.

Comment: could you explain that in more detail please. Sorry I'm a noob to this stuff

Comment: it was about importing your custom button. Just use ImageButton and in xml put android:background="@drawable/my_custom_button_image"

Comment: Okay so I got the white box to go away, but how do I position the button where I want it?

Comment: Please I'm stuck can someone help?