# How do you rearrange buttons in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you rearrange buttons where you want them in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931545/how-do-you-rearrange-buttons-where-you-want-them-in-eclipse)

Hey guys I am having trouble with placing my buttons in my XML layout. I already have a background and was just trying to put 3 buttons near the middle and thats where I'm having trouble. I know about center gravity and all that but could you help me? Also, If I made my own buttons can I just import them using the image button thing, or is that not right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't ask a question twice.  You already asked it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931545/how-do-you-rearrange-buttons-where-you-want-them-in-eclipse

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get a definite answer. I won't do it again.

Comment: Please show your Layout XML. So the things can be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange elements of your layout by editing the XML directly or by dragging and dropping in the outline view or the graphical layout view (I find the latter harder to do reliably).

To use your custom views, click on the "Custom & Library Views" button in the graphical layout palette, or just type in the fully qualified class name as the view tag in the XML.

Comment: Okay I'm still kind of confused. What properties do I change to make the button move? Also, when I clicked on the Custom and Library View button all that was under there was a button that said refresh.

Comment: Do you want to _rearrange_ buttons (like your title says) or just move them around within the parent? If the latter, you should look at the `layout_*` properties; the details depend on the type of the parent container. As to the Custom and Library View being empty -- have you defined any custom view classes in your project?

Comment: Well I got them in the right spot by trial and error. But, I just had to image buttons in the XML that I wanted to center and put near the bottom. Also, do you know how to make it so when you push down on the button it changes color to show you pushed it. Its an image button though.

Comment: Glad you got it working. For the color change, you need to define your background as a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). You define a separate background drawable for each state, then reference them in the state list drawable, indicating which to use for each button state you want to differentiate visually.

Comment: So what I got from that is that I have to make a seperate XML layout and save it in the drawable folder? and then put this code in <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>

Comment: Yes, something like that should do what you want.